# Python: Splitting a string, split by variable

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to write a function that will allow me to pass in a string and a character to split the string by.

This obviously works:

```
def delimit(inputValue, splitChar):
   splitValue = [x.strip() for x in inputValue.split(',')]
   print(splitValue)

delimit('100,    200,300   ,400,500',',')
```

Printing this:

`['100', '200', '300', '400', '500']`

But when I try to use a variable to specify the delimiting value, it doesn't work:

```
def delimit(inputValue, splitChar):
    splitChar = "'" + splitChar + "'"
    splitValue = [x.strip() for x in inputValue.split(splitChar)]
    print(splitValue)

delimit('100,    200,300   ,400,500',',')
```

Which returns:

`['100,    200,300   ,400,500']`

Is it possible to use a variable inside of `split()`?  If so, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a variable for your `splitChar`.
I think you are getting confused by other languages where single quotes denote char's while double quotes denote strings. In Python there is no difference between single quoted and double quoted strings. There also is no concept of a char type, only single character strings.

To make your function work you just need to remove your line `splitChar = "'" + splitChar + "'"` since this is making your `splitChar` string be `','` which is not what you want. `splitChar` is already storing the correct delimeter `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you add this line `splitChar = "'" + splitChar + "'"`? 
Now, the split char variable contains `','`, which doesn't appear anywhere in your test string. Thus, split fails to split it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you take out `splitChar = "'" + splitChar + "'"` from your function, it will work. Concatenating "'" on either side of your split character will just add ' to each side of you split character string.